# pandas dividing by condition

Tags: pandas, division

I have a pandas dataframe df with the contents below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'y': [15, 10, 5]})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT7nK.png)

I would like to get a third column that shows the result of dividing by the value in y when x=c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3e94.png)

I tried some but not worked:

```
df['z'] = df['y']/df.loc[df['x']== 'c', 'y']
```

Comment: It looks like it should work on the sample data. What's wrong at your end?

Comment: probably make the loc part an array : ``df.y / df.loc[df.x == "c", "y"].array``

Comment: Do you have multiple "c" values? You can use `iloc[0]` to pick the first one of them: `df['y'] / df.loc[df['x'] == 'c', "y"].iloc[0]`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you Sammy and David.